# Firebird 2.5 + EF6, how to set transaction to wait

Tags: transactions, firebird, entity-framework-6

How can I set transactions in EF6 with firebird provider 4.0 EF6 to wait. Default is no wait, so I get a lot of exceptions.

To set the transaction isolation level, I use `dbContext.Database.StartTransaction()`. I try to use isolation level serializable to serialize the access to one table. I only read a value, add a constant and write that new value back.

I always got the exception `lock conflict on no wait transaction`, that's why I want to use a transaction that wait until the other has ended.

Comment: Lock conflicts should be pretty rare, what isolation level do you use, or are you updating the same records from a lot of different clients (or threads)?

Comment: As I wrote above I use serializable. And yes I read the same record from different clients and update that record.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `BeginTransaction` overload on `FbConnection` where you can specify `TPB` thus whatever you want Firebird related. Then use [`UseTransaction`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.database.usetransaction%28v=vs.113%29.aspx) method to tell Entity Framework to use that transaction.

Comment: So, there is no way to stay database independent? I use the EF with some databases like MS-SQL, Firebird, Oracle etc. (it depends which database is in use at the customer).

Comment: How can you stay independent if you're using something that's Firebird specific (specifying wait/nowait TPB)?

Comment: I use isolationlevel serialize and with ms-sql it waits 'til the first transactions ends. FB does not. That's why I will change FB behaviour. That's all. :-)

Comment: Yes, because Firebird let's you choose what behavior you want. The no-wait is default in the driver.

Comment: Is it possible to set the behavior in the connection string?

Comment: No, it's not possible.